# Troubleshooting unlink() permission denied

Tags: php, windows

I've a webpage written in PHP where I play a video through default HTML5 player.

From this webpage I can click a link that goes to another page where I can delete the video I was playing to but, doing so, provides me a "permission denied" error.

I tried to debug myself the issue and I found out that the video file I was trying to unlink() was being used by the Apache process so it's not related to permissions.

Anybody has any clue on how to resolve this somehow?

Also, forgot to say I'm running the service on XAMPP (Windows).

Comment: If you're running XAMPP on Windows, why your question is tagged in `linux`.

 I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that when you try to delete the file, it is being served by Apache, so you get an error when calling unlink.

Instead of deleting the video file you should make it unavailable, so new users cannot access the file. You can then delete the file at a later stage